# How to replace month name with number in R

Tags: python, r

I have python code that converts the months in a column to numbers and names a new column

```
df['arrival_date_month_number'] = df['arrival_date_month'].replace(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September', 'October', 'November','December'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]).astype(str).astype(int)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0pQK.png)
This is the month in the original dataset and I want it to be represented as a number
For example January = 1, February = 2

refer to the python code how to replace month name with number in R.Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not very helpful, show us your data and what your desired outcome is. Also, R data frames cannot have numbers for columns names.

Comment: I have update the question, please check

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `match` and `month.names`:

```r
# setup
dat <- data.frame(month_name =  month.name[sample(1:12, size = 12)])
dat
#>    month_name
#> 1        June
#> 2     October
#> 3    November
#> 4         May
#> 5    February
#> 6        July
#> 7       April
#> 8    December
#> 9   September
#> 10    January
#> 11      March
#> 12     August

# turn month names into numbers
dat$month_no <- match(dat$month_name, month.name)
dat
#>    month_name month_no
#> 1        June        6
#> 2     October       10
#> 3    November       11
#> 4         May        5
#> 5    February        2
#> 6        July        7
#> 7       April        4
#> 8    December       12
#> 9   September        9
#> 10    January        1
#> 11      March        3
#> 12     August        8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, Still some confused for me. I want to implement replace the month_name to number. For example, original column is present by month name like January, March. I want to replace to number with this column

Comment: If you don't want to create a new column then just reasign the existing column: `dat$month_name <- match(dat$month_name, month.name)`

Answer (score -1):

```
df[,'new_col'] <- NA
df$new_col[df$old_col == "January"] <- 1
df$new_col[df$old_col == "February"] <- 2
```

and so on

Comment: Add enough details so that it makes sense to future readers.